# Asp.Net Ajax controls documentation?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, client-side

I am having quite trouble finding client side functionality of Asp.net Ajax controls like calendarextender etc etc. How can i find which Client side functionality each control or Calendar control has?
I have only found these properties

._selectedDate and ._textbox.set_Value()

I want to restrict one calendar on the basis of second calendar value. if i have selected March 1 then second calendar start date should be March 1 and cannot select previous dates.

Comment: I highly recomend using jQuery's [datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/) as the controls provided in AJAX Control Toolkit are very slow and poorly documented.

Comment: thanks but i do not know how to use that I mean how can i take values on server side and setting values from server side to it. are you getting my point

Comment: Common way to do it is use a HiddenField

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To name just a few:

```
    this._enabled
    this._animated
    this._buttonID
    this._layoutRequested
    this._layoutSuspended
    this._button = null
    this._popupMouseDown
    this._selectedDate
    this._startDate
    this._endDate
    this._visibleDate
```

I recommend downloading the source from here: [ASP.NET Ajax Control Toolkit](http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets).  Then, expand the MicrosoftAjax.Extended project and you'll see a Calendar folder.  There, you'll find the js you are looking for.

Comment: thanks mate it was matter of seconds to know the solution.function CheckDate(sender, args) {

            var cal = $find("calendarextender2");
            cal._startDate = sender._selectedDate;
            
        }